# Cosa significa "levare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Il Maestro era anche il ministro degli Esteri, l'ambasciatore plenipotenziario, il regista sapiente di una comunicazione - come adesso si dice - tutta giocata in **levare**: poche apparizioni di grande significato, destinate a lasciare un segno.

Ho cercato il verbo "levare" in parecchi dizionari e ho trovato molte accezioni. Tuttavia, non capisco a quale si riferisca questo vocabolo nel passaggio precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: "Levare" significa togliere, sottrarre. Credo che in questo caso intenda che la strategia di comunicazione era basata sull'attuare poche cose ma significative anziché un gran numero di iniziative. In questo senso "levare" significa appunto sottrarre, al posto di aggiungere (apparizioni, eventi,eccetera)

Comment: Io trovo che sia una sovrapposizione fra quello che dice @RiccardoDeContardi e la classica locuzione “in levare” (contrapposta a “in battere”) che fa riferimento al tempo debole di una struttura ritmica (cf. “[levare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/levare/)”, accezione 6.b), sempre nel senso quindi di un comportamento attenuato, understated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tratta di una metafora tratta dal linguaggio musicale.

"Suonare in levare" in musica indica spostare l'[accento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(music)) per mettere in evidenza il "colpo debole". La tecnica in inglese dovrebbe chiamarsi ["offbeat"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/offbeat). Utilizzare questa tecnica serve a dare più pienezza ad un ritmo e può "stupire" le persone che non si aspettano questo effetto che compare in maniera irregolare rispetto al "battere" che è il classico colpo del ritmo.

In questo caso, quindi, "una comunicazione tutta giocata in levare" indica che fa della sorpresa il suo punto di forza.

Non ha un utilizzo nel parlare comune ma io gli ho dato questo significato in base anche alla piccola spiegazione successiva "poche apparizioni di grande significato, destinate a lasciare un segno" che è la stessa descrizione che si può dare a "suonare in levare" in musica:

https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/in-levare.

Comment: Ti riferisci a iniziare un brano musicale [in questo modo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacrusis)?

Comment: [Qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=ugqC89rsw_UC&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=film+%22in+levare%22+regista&source=bl&ots=Qns0PURigG&sig=KZzJpJ8InKdgmDa-P0tQtwM4i8c&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl2vq98o3VAhXJWhQKHfUvB18Q6AEIFDAD) si usa l'espressione "in levare" per parlare delle scelte registiche di un film: se ho capito bene quello che si spiega sarebbe più o meno quello che dici nella tua risposta.

Comment: Non sono un gran musicista quindi non so spiegartelo benissimo a parole e rischierei di farti fare solo confusione. Un video che spiega ai musicisti come fare i colpi in levare può essere [questo](https://youtu.be/jFySR75J7VI).

Comment: Quindi, se ho capito bene,  si tratta di mettere l'[accento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(music)) in un posto inaspettato per produrre qualche tipo di ritmo sincopato.

Comment: Ma allora la traduzione in inglese penso che debba essere ["offbeat"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/offbeat).

Comment: Io toglierei l'espressione "battuta in levare" dal finale della risposta perché penso corrisponda al termine "anacrusi" (vedi il mio primo commento e anche [qui](http://www.edizionicurci.it/tipbook/glossario.asp?id=683&id_libro=9&nome=Leggere%20la%20musica)) che è tutt'altra cosa rispetto a quello di cui stai parlando (se ho capito bene), che sarebbe uno spostamento dell'accento in una battuta musicale. Forse potresti scrivere "suonare in levare".

Comment: Mi sono permessa di fare qualche modifica: così la risposta mi sembra più precisa.